# reduplicate request in apache logs

Tags: apache, http-server

**1. Symptom:**

I found lots of requests for the same resource on Apache logs, like this:

```
/image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 206 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 206 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 206 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
10.83.140.23 - - [29/Dec/2011:08:50:10 +0800] "GET /image/default/dHtmTreeImg/iconUnCheckAll.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 120
```

I searched a lot still don't understand why this happens? How to prevent this happens?  Thanks.

**2. Environment**

Apache: 2.2
OS: windows 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are requests for an image associated with the [dhtmlxTree script](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/) ([cf](https://www.google.com/search?q=iconUnCheckAll.gif).), which you're presumably using somewhere on your site. The response code seems to be [200](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), so no problem.

What's the confusion?

Comment: I think the problem is he's getting the same request 20 times in a second.

Comment: yes, why 20 times in one second!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem for your web server. It's the client who sends the same request multiple times. Maybe an old IE, or any browser/application that does not use cache.